# I created a custom Odoo module and it's showing parse error when i want to upgrade it

Tags: python, xml, module, odoo, odoo-14

Here is the error message i am getting.

```
ValueError: Invalid field 'view_type' on model 'ir.actions.act_window'
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/c:/users/shaileshbhai/pycharmprojects/odoodev/extra_addons/demo_hospital/view/patient.xml:15, near
<record id="patient_action_new" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">patient name</field>
            <field name="res_model">hospital.patient</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        </record>
```

Comment: That should be more in the error message. And please tell us the Odoo version. I can add the tag, if needed.

Comment: My Odoo version is 14 and it's showing one more message "ValueError: Invalid field 'view_type' on model 'ir.actions.act_window'"

Comment: that's what i was suspecting :D the field isn't there anymore so just remove the line with that field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The field `view_type` was removed in one of the latest Odoo versions. Just remove it from your action definitions and you're fine.

Comment: Now all view types are `form` by default. But, what about the views called *list views*, which used `<field name="view_type">tree</field>`? They allowed users to deploy child records from parents. How can we make a view like that now?

Comment: I think Odoo removed that in newer versions. I didn't find modules adding it again :-(